# SetOnEventListener for component that is designed on XML

Tags: java, android

I wrote a simple app with a TextView inside the Layout. The design on XML is:

I tried 2 methods to add click event to this TextView:

**Method 1. Add onClick property to the TextView tag => This method works normally.**

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
        android:onClick="msgOnClick"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and Java file:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView txtMsg = findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void msgOnClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

**Method 2. I use above design (without onclick property) and use setOnClickListener as follows:**

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView txtMsg = findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
        txtMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

This method 2 cannot work. Although there is no error, but when I launch app in simulator/device, the program halts.

What is problem here? I know exactly the reason is caused by setOnClickListener. If I use an element that is designed by XML of Activity, I cannot use the method setOnClickListener. That looks like Android studio make some configuration to generate the method setOnClickListener, and we just add this property to the component tag. Is that right?
Thanks in advance !

The tracing is here

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: localglobal, PID: 8342
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{localglobal/MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                         at localglobal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)

Comment: The initialization of txtMsg is before setcontentView layout so please start writing code after setting the layout. I hope it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set content view.

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Before the findViewById

Answer (score 0):

You got NullPointerException because **textview not intialized**. You find textview id before setContentView. So, do like this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView txtMsg = findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
    txtMsg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

}
```

}